# SQL - find id for all ids that meet condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to SQL query this database below:

Trying to find out errors in my system which is tracking the following people who enter and exit my gantry. Technically you must first exit then you can have another entry. So i'm trying to find users whose exit time is before their next entry. We ignore refunds whereby the exit time will be ***Null*** or ***blank***.

To find the `r_id` (receipt_ID) for every user whereby current `date_time_out` (when they exit) is before their next receipt's `date_time_in` (when they entered again). I need to return all their unique receipt ids for these users as these are errors.

example db:

```
r_id | user_id |  date_time_in | date_time_out   | date_time_refund

0001 | 12345   | 21/02/19 01:00| 23/02/19 01:12

0002 | 12345   | 21/02/19 01:10| 23/02/19 01:15

0003 | 12345   | 21/02/19 01:16| 23/02/19 01:17

0009 | 12346   | 21/02/19 01:02| _____Null______ | 23/02/19 01:03

0010 | 12346   | 21/02/19 01:02| 23/02/19 01:03
```

expected output (ascending):

```
0001

0002
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please tag your question only with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff my bad. done

Answer (score 0):

you could use a self join

```
select a.r_id , b.r_id
from my_table a 
inner join my_table b on a.user_id = b.user_id 
        and a.date_time_out > b.date_time_in 
        and a.date_time_out is nul null 
order by a.r_id asc
```

or for separated row

```
  select * from my_table  m 
  inner join  
  (
      select a.r_id id1 , b.r_id id2
      from my_table a 
      inner join my_table b on a.user_id = b.user_id 
              and a.date_time_out > b.date_time_in 
              and a.date_time_out is nul null 
  ) t on m.r_id = t.id1 or m.r_id = id2 
  order by m.r_id asc
```

Comment: sorry, not sure i understand you as i would require the r_id to belong to the user. example:
user 12345 with r_id 0001,0002 will be outputted as for each id we are looking for the next receipt of this particular id (if exists) and check the entry for this "next" receipt against our current receipt exit time. If our current exit < next entry, we flag it out for that particular user.

Comment: appreciate your time bro, but does not work :(.
i just need the r_id per error - where the user_id(12345) has a current exit(1:12) and this user_id's(12345) next receipt has an entry(1:10) before his current exit. flag it out.

i guess whats missing is the check next row for same user and select his exit time to compare against the previous row for same user

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `r_id` is capturing the sequence of the records, use `exists`:

```
select e.*
from example e
where exists (select 1
              from example e2
              where e2.user_id = e.user_id and
                    e2.r_id > e.r_id and
                    e2.date_time_in < e.date_time_out
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from example e2
              where e2.user_id = e.user_id and
                    e2.r_id < e.r_id and
                    e2.date_time_in > e.date_time_out
             );
```